# How to run EJB remote application client jar without any IDE?

Tags: glassfish, client, ejb

Using NetBeans, I made a very simple EJB application client (and a EJB server, of course) which runs on Glassfish and uses a jar with the EJB remote interface. The application works without problems.

But I decided to run the ".jar" (which is the application client itself) on a remote machine, with Java SE, Java EE, and Glassfish installed. I searched for a while and it seems to be very simple (using Glassfish command line). Can someone help me please?

Thanks.